# Application runs in Windows 7 but not in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have created an app for back up and restore of computers. I also allows modification of ADObjects through the use of custom `Profile.ps1` file. The app runs fine in the ISE with no errors and works properly no errors in Windows 7. However, when I try to run it in a newly imaged Windows 10 machine I get "Property Can Not Be Found" errors on all my object properties.

The thing is I can read all the properties when I fill comboboxes fine. The error only occurs when the form is submitted. I will attach 1 of the forms I am having a problem with. Again it runs fine in Windows 7, but not Windows 10.

Could this be a problem with Microsoft updates?

Also, yes, I am setting `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Error message:

```
The property 'company' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exist and can be set.
+ $CO.company = $company
+ Categoryinfo :InvalidOperation: (:) [] RuntimeExeption
```

Code:

```ps
. \\iotsdsp01pw\installs$\MoveToOU\PcDeployment\Profile.ps1

#region Validation Functions
function Validate-IsEmail ([string]$Email) {
  return $Email -match "^(?("")("".+?""@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$"
}

function Validate-IsURL ([string]$Url) {
  if ($Url -eq $null) {
    return $false
  }

  return $Url -match "^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?$"
}

function Validate-IsName ([string]$Name, [int]$MaxLength) {
  if ($MaxLength -eq $null -or $MaxLength -le 0) {
    #Set default length to 40
    $MaxLength = 40
  }

  return $Name -match "^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,$MaxLength}$"
}

function Validate-IsIP ([string]$IP) {
  return $IP -match "\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
}

function Validate-IsEmptyTrim ([string]$Text) {
  if ($text -eq $null -or $text.Trim().Length -eq 0) {
    return $true
  }

  return $false
}

function Validate-IsEmpty ([string]$Text) {
  return [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Text)
}

function Validate-IsDate ([string]$Date) {
  return [DateTime]::TryParse($Date, [ref](New-Object System.DateTime))
}
#endregion

$No_Load = {
  $NewForm.Close()
  #Initialize variables
  $dateTime = Get-Date -Format G
  $userName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property UserName).UserName
  $computerName = $env:computername

  #Varables for display
  $distinguishedName = (Get-dn computer cn $computerName)
  $computerObject = (Get-ADObject $distinguishedName)
  $organizationalUnit = (Get-ADObject "OU=Agencies, DC=state, DC=in, DC=us")

  #Initialize Form Controls
  $lblUserNameNewNo.Text = $userName
  $lblComputerNameNewNo.Text = $computerName
  $lblPhysicalLocationNewNo.Text = $computerObject.location
  $txtBillingCodeNewNo.Text = $computerObject.departmentNumber
  $comboboxAccountTypeNewNo.Text = $computerObject.extensionAttribute15
  $comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo.Text = $computerObject.company
  Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo ($organizationalUnit.children | %{ $_.OU })
}

#region Control Helper Functions
function Load-ComboBox {
  Param (
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]$ComboBox,
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    $Items,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [string]$DisplayMember,
    [switch]$Append
  )

  if (-not $Append) {
    $ComboBox.Items.Clear()
  }

  if ($Items -is [Object[]]) {
    $ComboBox.Items.AddRange($Items)
  } elseif ($Items -is [Array]) {
    $ComboBox.BeginUpdate()
    foreach ($obj in $Items) {
      $ComboBox.Items.Add($obj)
    }
    $ComboBox.EndUpdate()
  } else {
    $ComboBox.Items.Add($Items)
  }

  $ComboBox.DisplayMember = $DisplayMember
}

#Validation
function ParameterValidate {
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [ValidateLength(1, 10)]
    [String]$Text
  )
  return $true
}

$comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo_Validating = [System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler]{
  #Check if the Name field is empty
  $result = Validate-IsEmptyTrim $comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo.Text
  if ($result -eq $true) {
    #Mark a failure only if the Validation failed
    $script:ValidationFailed = $true
    #Display an error message
    $errorprovider1.SetError($comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo, "Please select agency.");
  } else {
    #Clear the error message
    $errorprovider1.SetError($comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo, "");
  }
}

$txtBillingCodeNewNo_Validating = [System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler]{
  #Check if the Name field is empty
  $result = Validate-IsEmptyTrim $txtBillingCodeNewNo.Text
  if ($result -eq $true) {
    #Mark a failure only if the Validation failed
    $script:ValidationFailed = $true
    #Display an error message
    $errorprovider1.SetError($txtBillingCodeNewNo, "Please enter billing code.");
  } else {
    #Clear the error message
    $errorprovider1.SetError($txtBillingCodeNewNo, "");
  }
}

$comboboxAccountTypeNewNo_Validating = [System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler]{
  $result = Validate-IsEmptyTrim $comboboxAccountTypeNewNo.Text
  if ($result -eq $true) {
    #Mark a failure only if the Validation failed
    $script:ValidationFailed = $true
    #Display an error message
    $errorprovider1.SetError($comboboxAccountTypeNewNo, "Please enter agency type.");
  } else {
    #Clear the error message
    $errorprovider1.SetError($comboboxAccountTypeNewNo, "");
  }
}

$control_Validated = {
  #Pass the calling control and clear error message
  $errorprovider1.SetError($this, "");
}

$No_FormClosing = [System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler]{
  #Event Argument: $_ = [System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs]
  #Validate only on OK Button
  if ($No.DialogResult -eq "OK") {
    #Init the Validation Failed Variable
    $script:ValidationFailed = $false
    #Validate the Child Control and Cancel if any fail
    $No.ValidateChildren()
    #Cancel if Validation Failed
    $_.Cancel = $script:ValidationFailed
  }
}

#Events
$buttonColor_Click = {
  #TODO: Place custom script here
  $colordialog1.ShowDialog()
}

$linklblViewListNewNo_LinkClicked = [System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler]{
  Start-Process "http://billingcodes.iot/"
}

$btnSubmitNewNo_Click = {
  #TODO: Place custom script here
  $company = $comboboxOrganizationalUnitNewNo.Text
  $departmentNumber = $txtBillingCodeNewNo.Text
  $accountType = $comboboxAccountTypeNewNo.Text

  if ($accountType -eq "Seat") {
    $accountType = " "
  }

  #Varables for Set-ADObject
  $computerObject.company = $company
  $computerObject.departmentNumber = $departmentNumber
  $computerObject.extensionAttribute15 = $accountType

  try {
    $computerObject.SetInfo()
    [Environment]::Exit(1)
  } catch {
    $labelDialogRedNewNo.Text = "AD computer object not found"
  }
}
```

Comment: I will point out that the W10 update a week or two ago broke the AD cmdlets on my machine. I didn't research to see if it was a common issue or not, I just fixed it.

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded but there realy isnt any code to post. the app works fine in W7 but does not work in W10. I am reading the propertys of the object fine for outputs. But when I attempt to modify them on Submit Click I get the following error: Example

Comment: A program that runs without code...amazing...

Comment: The property  'company' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exist and can be set.                                                                                         + $CO.company = $company                                                                      +Categoryinfo :InvalidOperation: (:) [] RuntimeExeption

Comment: How is $CO populated? Also, you should be editing your question, not adding comments to show the code.

Comment: For what it is worth, based on the code that you posted, I suspect that you are notgetting an AD Object. For instance you are getting the distinguished name using a function named Get-DN, but there is no such function in the code that you posted.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, This was the problem. I have been writing c# so long I was not thinking about scope. You helped allot. Sorry for the terrible posts. Also I went back and check my answers that helped. This was my first go at Powershell. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your culprit (from what I can see):

```
$No_Load = {
  ...
  $computerObject = (Get-ADObject $distinguishedName)
  ...
}
...
$btnSubmitNewNo_Click = {
  ...
  $computerObject.company = $company
  ...
}
```

You assign a computer object to the variable `$computerObject` in one scriptblock, and try to change one of its properties in another scriptblock. However, to be able to share a variable between scriptblocks you need to make it a *global* variable, otherwise you have two separate *local* variables that know nothing about each other.

```
$No_Load = {
  ...
  $global:computerObject = Get-ADObject $distinguishedName
  ...
}
...
$btnSubmitNewNo_Click = {
  ...
  $global:computerObject.company = $company
  ...
}
```

BTW, I doubt that this ever worked in Windows 7, since it failed with the same error on my Windows 7 test box.